# Android: really cannot believe there's not a good and free chart library with touch event handling

Tags: android, charts

i am searching for a free Chart Library for Android that can handle touch event on a item.
All the free libraries that i've seen (achartengine, droidcharts and other) do not support it.

Can anyone help me in finding a native library (i know i can do in html5 but i would like to work in native java code) with touch enabled charts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

AChartEngine offer support for :

- zoom (buttons and pinch)
- pan
- touch to get selected value

Is there any other interaction that you need?

Dan

Comment: i've not found that AChartEngine has touch to get selected value... it is really what i'm looking for and don't find in any free Android chart library. Android is really a delusion for this.

Comment: Look again at AChartEngine. It does have that.